# I want to store image and the corresponding data in db using php

Tags: php

I want to store images along with other form of data in database using php.
It was working fine, but since I validated the form in other fields its not storing images anymore but only storing data.

Comment: It's really bad practise to store an image in the database, the best method will be to upload it to a filesystem by using PHP, then you can store the filepath in the database so you can still have a relation between the two.

Comment: You're probably mis-handling the upload data, and/or not inserting it correctly, and/or failing to check for failed uploads and simply assume it worked. But since you've provided no code whatsoever, we can provide no help whatsoever. And as a general rule, do **NOT** store image data in a database. There's very few usage cases that justify it, and far too many gotchas to make it worthwhile.

Comment: Even if people were to recommend storing image data in the database directly, there's not nearly enough information in this question to work out what the problem is. Please always offer the necessary information to help us to help you - usually that's PHP code, HTML markup, and detail about whatever debugging you've done.

Comment: Could you please supply any code before and after you added the validation so we can see what's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

While its possible to upload a file to the DB, I'd suggest storing the file in the filesystem instead and just keeping its path in the DB.

http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/uploading-files-to-mysql-database.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can upload and store images directly into the database. However, it is not the suggested way to do it. Instead, you need to store it under any specific directory in the server and store its URL in the database under text field.

If you are having problem with uploading the image via a `form` in HTML (using `POST` method), have a look at this link - Have a look at this link - [POST method uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)